# Form of "What?" for hearing loss

Tags: word-usage, translation, phrase-request

What is the Italian form of "What" meaning "I didn't hear or understand, please repeat what you said."

Comment: Short form: "Scusi?" or "Prego?".
Long form: "Scusi, può ripetere?" or "Per cortesia, può ripetere?"

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 13):

Informal: Come? Cosa? Eh? Come/Cosa/Che hai detto?

Formal, (as suggested in a comment by @RiccardoDeContardi): Scusi? Prego? Può ripetere? Come/Cosa/Che ha detto?, the latest two usually followed by a further courtesy locution such as per favore/scusi/per cortesia.